# AJAX Абсолютный путь к файлу

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Есть код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funcBefore()
        {
            $("#content").text("Загрузка");
        }

        function funcSuccess(data)
        {
            $("#content").text(data);
        }

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#load").bind("click", function ()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://ajax.example.com/",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({name: "Admin", pass: "123"}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: funcBefore,
                    success: funcSuccess
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="load">Загрузить данные</p>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но при этом результат не возвращается. Что делать?

Comment: URL правильно указан?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш ajax-запрос отрабатывает с ошибкой и функция, указанная в свойстве `success`, просто не вызывается. Это происходит из-за несуществующего поддомена, указанного в `url`, по этой причине ваш запрос ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Пот домен есть такой, это пример ссылки.

Comment: Тогда напишите в вопросе, какой ответ приходит от сервера и код состояния HTTP. Для этого в `success` пропишите `function(data) { console.log(data); }`.